# Importing geojson with react and next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, geojson

I am trying to load a geojson file into a react component that also uses next.js. When the extension is changed to json, it works fine. The problem is that with the geojson extension, it doesn't know how to handle the file. When I alter the next.config.js file as below, I get the error below.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.geojson$/,
      use: ["json-loader"]
    });

    return config;
  },
  devIndicators: {
    autoPrerender: false,
  },
}
```

And here is the error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'json-loader' in ...
```

How do I tell a next.js react app how to read in a new format?

Comment: Did you install `json-loader` in the first place? Seems to be the right approach

Comment: Yes. I ran npm i json-loader but it isn't showing up on the package.json

Comment: You need `npm i --save-dev json-loader` to save `json-loader` as a development dependency.

Comment: I tried that as well. Nothing

Comment: The json-loader is supposed to be included with next.js, but I don't know how to point the geojson files to that loader.

Comment: Yes and no, it is included in recent versions of Webpack but only for `.json` as stated by `json-loader` doc. In your scenario, with a custom extension, you seem to still need it. I can't tell what is wrong at this point.

Comment: What is the proper method to tell next.json that geojson files should be read in with the json-loader

Comment: I just tried out your code locally with an installed json-loader and it worked fine for me. So if you follow @EricBurel s advice, you should be fine.